# How is Louise what she is in the Red Garden OVA: Dead Girls?

Tags: red-garden

In the OVA sequel, we are introduced to Louise who looks exactly like Lise in the *Red Garden* TV series. Lise is last seen dying the Animus death of turning into ashes on Roosevelt Island, so it is generally taken that Louise is a reincarnation of Lise. Later on, Louise revealed her identity as an android. (Gasp!)

[image: Louise the android]

How could Lise, a human girl turned Animus infected with the cursed Doral blood, reincarnate as an android? What happened during the 300-year time span between the end of the TV series and the beginning of the OVA to have caused this inconceivable transition in Lise's identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies within the OVA's title, *Dead Girls*. The OVA is a homage to the 1992 debut [novel of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Girls) by British science fiction author Richard Calder, which

> tell[s] the tale of a virus that turns pubescent girls into vampiric gynoid dolls called Lilim, and the doomed love affair between 15-year-old Ignatz Zwakh and a Lilim assassin called Primavera.

What's more, it appears that the TV series has also drawn inspiration from the *Dead Girls* novel, as the Animus-Doral feud and the conditions affecting members of the two warring clans match well with the rivalry between Cartier and Kito and the conditions affecting their dolls:

> years ago during a trade war Cartier infected Kito's fake dolls with an impotence STD and in response Kito sent her own virus to infect the genuine Cartier dolls in Paris - a virus that Morgenstern thinks responsible for the doll plague.

To answer my own question, Louise was probably born a human, but was turned into an android upon contracting a virus similar to that in the novel.